# Proof of a separating theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

The claim is the following: Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space and let $C \subset V $ be convex and non-empty such that $0 \notin C$. Then there exists some $l \in \operatorname{Hom}(V,\mathbb{R})$ such that $l_{\vert C} \ge 0$ and $l(C) \neq \{0\}$.

Proof. Induction over $\dim V$: For $\dim V = 1$ the claim is clear. Let $\dim V = n+1$. Then let $H$ be an n-dimensional hyperplane intersecting $C$. Set $D = H \cap C$. By induction hypothesis, one has a $u \in\operatorname{Hom}(H,\mathbb{R})$ with $u_{\vert D} \ge 0$ and $u(D) \neq \{0\}$. Now let $p_H : V \rightarrow H$ be the canonical projection. Now define $l := u \circ p_H$.Then one has $l_C \ge 0$ and $l(C) \neq \{0\}$.

For some reason, I think this proof is incorrect, but I can't spot the mistake.

Comment: Why is the claim clear in dimension 1?

Comment: @user25959 If dim = 1, then $C$ is some real interval. Since $0 \notin C$ we  either have that all elements in $C$ are $> 0$ or $< 0$. In the first case we set $l(c) = c$ and in the second case we set $l(c) = -c$.

Comment: It seems right to me.

Comment: @user25959 Most proofs of such theorems which are familiar to me are way more complicated. I just can't believe that this follows actually so trivially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is correct. It is so simple because it is only giving to you that $u$ is nonzero on **some** elements of $C$, but it will be zero on many. If you take $H$ to "barely" cross $u$, then $u$ will be zero on most of $C$.

The proof would be harder if you were trying to find a $u$ that is nonzero for all but one point of $C$.